# getAllGroups throws exception on Android in Titanium

Tags: android, mobile, contacts, titanium

I am using Titanium to develop an application to run on both iPhone and Android. Part of the app is to allow the user to select a dialing groups from the Contacts on the phone. This works just fine on iPhone, but always throws an error on Android.

The documentation does not state that groups are unavailable in Contacts on Android, but when I call Ti.Contacts.getAllGroups() on any android device I get the following exception:

Cannot find function getAllGroups in object [Ti.Contacts]. (file:///android_asset/Resources/lib/contacts.js#4) E/KrollCallback( 1141): org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getAllGroups in object [Ti.Contacts]. (file:///android_asset/Resources/lib/contacts.js#4)

Are groups not available through Ti.Contacts on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not supported on Android, take a look at the documentation page... see there is only a little apple in the corner

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Contacts.Group-object.html